# Multiple mysql database queries in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP document which contains mostly html, but also some MySql queries which look like this:

```
<?php
require_once('connectdata.php');

$db = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_BENUTZER, DB_PASSWORT, DB_NAME);

$myquery = "SELECT name FROM Entries WHERE typ = 'Communication' ORDER BY name";

$result = mysqli_query($db, $myquery);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result))
 {
 echo "$row->name";

 }

mysqli_close($db);
```

I am using this exact code several times in my document to echo the data I want to display.
Is this a good practice or is there a way to just connect once get all the data and echo them later in the document?

Is it bad if I leave it like that?

Comment: On a side note, I recommend using PHP's PDO feature. http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have your connection. When you have to make a query just use the syntax:

```
$myquery = "SELECT name FROM Entries WHERE typ = 'Communication' ORDER BY name";
```

You can include :

```
$db = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_BENUTZER, DB_PASSWORT, DB_NAME);
```

in your `connectdata.php` file, which you only include ONCE per file(where is needed).

Comment: ok and when do i close the connection then? with the last query in my document?

Comment: Someone can correct me if I am wrong, but I think PHP will close the connection automatically at the end of the script exec. But yes you can call close at the end yourself.

Comment: @NathanH yes, php will close the connection when the script is done. If its a script that will take a lot of time to execute it might be a good idea to release the connection/s when they are not needed any more tho.

Comment: @Nathan H you're right. PHP does close the connection at the end of the script execution.

Comment: With the slight exception of persistent connections